# Laravel model relation within same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am working on a Laravel 5.7 project where I have three tables `words`, `synonym_word` and `antonym_word`.

- `words` table has two columns `id` and `word`
- `synonym_word` has three columns `id`, `word_id` and `synonym_id`
- `antonym_word` has three columns `id`, `word_id` and `antonym_id`

I am storing all words, their synonyms and antonyms in Words table and referencing synonyms and antonyms in respective tables.

**Word.php**

```
class Word extends Model
{
    public function synonyms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Synonym');
    }

    public function antonyms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Antonym');
    }
}
```

I am querying synonyms like this:-

```
$synonyms = Word::find(1)->synonyms;
```

The above query is giving all synonyms and their id's from the `Synonym` table, but my actual synonym word is stored in `Words` table.

How can I get synonym words from `Words` table?

Comment: Please show me your Synonym model content.

Answer (score 1):

```
$synonymsWithWord = Word::find(1)->synonyms()->with('word')->get();
```

to use this, Synonyms class should have relation defined with Word as below.

```
class Synonym extends Eloquent {

    public function word()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Word');
    }

}
```

Read this same scenario for more understanding.
[Trying to get a post with comments and user name](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/trying-to-get-a-post-with-comments-and-user-name)

Comment: Yes, I have Synonym and Antonym Models like this. But the problem is Synonym and Antonym table does not store the actual word, the actual Synonym word is in Words table. Synonym table has only word_id field which refer back to words table.

Comment: $synonymsWithWord = Word::find(1)->synonyms()->with('word'); this query is giving me word_id's from Synonym table but not the actual word. I want to get the actual word from Words table.

Comment: Synonym and Antonym model should have relation with Word Model as suggested in Answer. And then use With function in Query.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh is it working ? Or any problem you are facing. Let me know. I will solve it.

Comment: thank you so much for giving me the idea. I solved it using nested relationship.

Comment: The scenario you have posted. No nested relationship was required. please vote me and support my answer. And share the points if any changes we have to made here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using dot (.) in the query.

**Word.php**

```
class Word extends Model
{
    public function antonyms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Antonym::class);
    }

    public function synonyms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Synonym::class);
    }
}
```

**Synonym.php**

```
class Synonym extends Model
{
    public function word()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Word::class);
    }
}
```

**WordController.php**

```
class WordController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $words = Word::with(['synonyms.word'])->get();
        return view('words', compact('words') );
    }   
}
```

**Notice the dot(.) between synonyms and word.**

**words.blade.php**

```
@foreach($words as $word)
    <h4>{{ $word->word }}</h4>
    @foreach($word->synonyms as $s)
        {{ $s->id }} - {{  $s->word->word }}
        <br>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```